# Upload file to Amazon S3 failing only first time

Tags: laravel-4, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files to amazon s3 bucket and its failing only first time. After first time, files upload successfully. Tried many ways can’t fix it. Please help.

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
Exception 'ErrorException' with message 'S3::inputFile(): Unable to open input file: C:\inetpub\temp\PHPTemp\php6C81.tmp' in C:\inetpub\websites\bizitask.com\app\libraries\S3.php:355
```

I am using an ajax form to upload the file and code in controller to upload the file is as follows:

```
if ($s3->putObjectFile(Input::file('file')->getRealPath(), 'bizitask', 'files/businesses/'.$business_id.'/'.$file_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) { return Redirect::to('customers/businesses/' . $business_id)->with('success', 'success'); }
```

I am using laravel 4.2

Comment: The first time since what? The first time for any file? The first time after the server is restarted? The first time you make the S3 bucket?

Comment: i have folders inside the bucket and whenever i want to upload something on the folder for the first time its showing the error.